# Where is the class assigned to when stored in a struct?

Tags: c#

I read a thread (which had the input of Marc Gravell and Jon Skeet) that mentioned if a struct is in a class, that struct is stored on the heap like the class.

What if a class is a member of a struct? Where does the class get assigned to?

Thanks

Comment: For info - there are also a number of ways that a struct local-**variable** (normally on the stack) ends on the heap; captured variables, iterator blocks, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this. This was actually mentioned by a member in the thread I mention above (I think struct vs class in C# it was called).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a class is a member of a struct, then only the **reference** is stored in the struct (i.e. the 32/64-bit address to the instance). The instance of a class is **always** on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

Still on the heap. The struct will only contain a reference to the class instance (like a pointer).